# Extracting and accumulate result from multiple HTTP request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, future

I met a problem that I cannot solve these days. I'm doing multiple http requests and in each response, it should have a `Array[DTAnnotation]`. I want to accumulate all the resulting list into one (this is not the problem here). My problem is that I cannot return the results from a `WSResponse`. What I try :

```
import mymodel.{DTFeatures, DTResponse, DTRequest, DTAnnotations}

def checkForSpike
  (
    awsKey : String,
    collection : JSONCollection,
    record : Record,
    features : Array[DTFeatures]
  ) : Unit = {
  val url = config.getString("url").getOrElse 
  val holder = WS.url(url)
  val complexHolder =
    holder.withHeaders(("Content-Type","application/json"))
  // excepting result is List[Array[DTAnnotations]] 
  val test : List[Array[DTAnnotations]] = 
  for(feature <- features) yield {
    val dtFeature = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(DTRequest(feature)))
    val futureResponse = complexHolder.post(dtFeature)
    Logger.info("Make the HTTP POST Request in " + (t1 - t0) + " msecs")
    futureResponse.map { response =>
      Logger.info("Get response in " + (System.currentTimeMillis - t1))
      if(response.status == 200) {
        response.json.validate[DTResponse].map { dtResponse =>
          // I want to return this 
          dtResponse.annotations 
        }.recoverTotal { _ =>
          Logger.debug("invalid json")
        }
      } else {
        Logger.debug(Json.prettyPrint(Json.obj("status" -> response.status, "body" -> response.body)))
      }
    }
        Await.result(futureResponse, 10.seconds)
  }
}
```

Because the response is a `Future`, I try to add a `Await` to get the annotations but I have one error at the typing phase :

```
[error]  found   : Array[play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse]
[error]  required: List[Array[DTAnnotation]]
```

How I can fix this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors that avoid this to work. I add a version that compiles with your expected type and if you have questions I will answer in the comments.

```
def checkForSpike
  (
    awsKey: String,
    collection: JSONCollection,
    record: Record,
    features: Array[DTFeatures]
  ): Unit = {
    val url = config.getString("url").getOrElse
    val holder = WS.url(url)
    val complexHolder =
      holder.withHeaders(("Content-Type", "application/json"))
    // excepting result is List[Array[DTAnnotations]]
    val test: List[Array[DTAnnotations]] =
      for (feature <- features.toList) yield {
        val dtFeature = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(DTRequest(feature)))
        val futureResponse = complexHolder.post(dtFeature)
        val futureAnnotations: Future[Array[DTAnnotations]] = futureResponse.map { response =>
          if (response.status == 200) {
            response.json.validate[DTResponse].map { dtResponse =>
              // I want to return this
              dtResponse.annotations
            }.recoverTotal { _ =>
              Logger.debug("invalid json")
              ??? // An Array response should be expected, maybe empty
            }
          } else {
            Logger.debug(Json.prettyPrint(Json.obj("status" -> response.status, "body" -> response.body)))
            ??? // An Array response should be expected, maybe empty
          }
        }

        Await.result(futureAnnotations, 10.seconds)
      }
  }
```

Issues:

- Features must be converted to List if you expect a list to be
  returned by the for comprehension
- The map on future response returns
  another future and this value should be used in the Await
- To make sure the type of futureAnnotations is correct in all the branches the type should be valid

Comment: Works like charm ! Thank also for your time and the comments

Comment: You are welcome. Once you have it working, you can improve it a bit. Avoid Wait and read about composing futures. The tutorials from Daniel Westheide are very good. This is the chapter about futures http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `flatMap` instead of `map` ?

Comment: No, my comment is more about learning to deal with futures. Specially avoid using Await, unless there is no other way.